# Using split() on a Javascript variable (and googlemaps geocoder)

Tags: javascript, split, google-geocoder

I think im missing something realyl stupid here... basically iam trying to get coordinates of a location by postocde (kinda irrelevant) by using this:

```
            geocoder.geocode({address: address}, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                onPostcodeLocation(results[0].geometry.location);
            } else {
                alert(address + ' not found');
            }
```

So this passes the lat/long values to the OnPostcodeLocation():

```
        function onPostcodeLocation(position) { 
          var positionVar = position;
          positionArray = position.split(",");
          alert(positionArray[0]);
      }
```

Now, if I alert() "position" in the first line of the onPostcodeLocation(), I get the correct value alerted, but as shown above im trying to split the values up to seperate variables. trying to put alert(positionArray[0]); doesnt do anything... what I am doing wrong????

Thanks

Comment: what does `alert(positionArray)` look like? And where is `positionArray` declared?

Comment: Hmmm... It seems I have nto declared it anywhere. That could be the problem! ill let you know in one minute..

Comment: Ok no that hasnt done anything by declaring it... is it something to do with the fact that its an object type thing im passing over to the function?? i.e. results[0].geometry.location?

Comment: and alert(positionArray) doesnt even happen. nothing after the line positionArray = position.split(","); gets alerted at all?? but just before it does, meaning theres something wrng with this line

Comment: Do you see any errors in the web console?

Comment: I cant use that becasuse this is for an app on my phone usiong phonegap... unless theres a console equivelant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a quick look at [the docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/) I've noticed that the `location` property isn't a string, or array but an object:

```
location : {
    "lat" : 37.42291810,
    "lng" : -122.08542120
}
```

So obviously, split won't work. Just `alert(position.lat)` or `alert(position.lng)`. Also: be weary of implied global variables, when using a variable in a function, always declare it first, better to declare it too much than not at all.

Comment: Ok yeah that makes sense. Just tried alerting position.lat and it came out with "function(){return this[a]}".. what is thisss??

Comment: Well, that location.lat exists, but it's a function that returns an array of sorts, just try alert(position.lat()) and `alert(position.lat()[0])` to see what's what, also spend some time on the man pages, there are many examples on it, I've not used this api yet, so I'm not 100% sure, but in those examples I've also seen code like `position.coords.longitude` used, either way: it's very well documented and open source, so you can always check the source for more info, too

Comment: Just so you know, it was "position.lat()" :)